# Cocos 2D - Moving Sprites on a tiled map

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm trying to move a sprite around a CCTMXMap in a smooth fashion.  I've figured out how (using CCActions) to move from tile to tile, but I get gaps in my animation (it pauses for a frame while it reevaluates which direction to walk).  I've tried moving the character in a scheduled update: method, but that gets messy when you try and restrict the sprite to only moving from tile to tile.  Any suggestions on how to get the clean, consistent animation without messy manual animation using update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, don't use actions. You'll always have the 1-frame delay problem when using CCActions.

Moving the sprite in update is really pretty simple. Especially if you restrict movement to a speed (points per frame) that is clearly divisible by the tile size. For example if your tiles are 40x30, then horizontal speeds of 1,2,4,8,10 would work fine. Vertically 1,2,3,5,6,10 would work.

Update the position by this number, cast it down to int, compare it with the destination location:

```
if ((int)currentPos.x == (int)targetPos.x && (int)currentPos.y == (int)targetPos.y)
{
    NSLog(@"I'm there!");
}
```

The reason for casting to int is to avoid rounding errors in floating point values.

Another solution would be - especially if your character can only move in one direction at a time - to figure out the number of frames it will take him to get there. If the character has to move 40 points to the right, and he moves at 4 points per frame, it'll take him 10 frames. Then just count the number of frames (how many times the update method ran) and if it reaches 10 (or 0 if you count down) then you know that the character has arrived without needing to check his position.